# Get the position of the collided sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I need to get the position of the last sprite that collided between 2 groups. All the sprites in a group have the same name. here is the concentrate code:

```
    rmog = pygame.sprite.Group()
    rmg = pygame.sprite.Group()


    class rmissileh(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self, image, speed):
             pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
             self.speed = -10
             self.speedx = 0
             self.image = redm
             self.rect = image.get_rect().move(s.rect.x+26,s.rect.y)


        def move(self):

             self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speedx, self.speed)redshot = 

rmissileh(redm, -10 )
rmg.add(redshot)


    class crmonstre(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, image, speed):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


            self.speedy = 2
            self.speedx = 1
            self.image = rmonstre
            self.step = 600
            self.rect = rmonstre.get_rect().move(500,-100)
        def move(self):
            self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speedx,self.speedy)

redmonstre = crmonstre(rmonstre,1)
rmog.add(redmonstre)
redmonstre = crmonstre(rmonstre,1)
rmog.add(redmonstre)
redmonstre = crmonstre(rmonstre,1)# I added only three but there is many more overtime.
rmog.add(redmonstre)
while stop:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
                    stop = False
            for redmonstre in rmog:
                fenetre.blit(fond, redmonstre.rect, redmonstre.rect)
                redmonstre.move()
                fenetre.blit(redmonstre.image,redmonstre.rect)

            if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(rmg, rmog,True ,True):
                fenetre.blit(fond, (0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
quit
```

As you can see when a redmonster collide with a redshot i have to blit the whole background(named "fond") because i don't know his position, if I print(redmonstre.rect.x) that will print the x position of the last object that i created and not the position of the one that collided.
And also in the while loop to blit a moving object i do :

```
for redmonstre in rmog:
    fenetre.blit(fond, redmonstre.rect, redmonstre.rect)
    redmonstre.move()
    fenetre.blit(redmonstre.image,redmonstre.rect)
```

i have many many for loop like that in my code and it doesn't feel right if you have an other way to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to find *just* the last collision. But here is how you could find all of the collisions, and hopefully that's a step in the right direction.

There are two ways you could do this. The first way would be to iterate through the list of sprites yourself. That would look kind of like this:

```
for sprite in rmg:
    #Note that spritecollide will remove every sprite that collides from 
    #rmog, but it will not remove 'sprite' from rmg. 
    if (pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, rmog, True)):
        print (sprite.x)
        rmg.remove(sprite)
```

[spritecollide docs.](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)

Here is the other way you could do it.

Look at the documentation for [pygame.sprite.groupcollide.](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) You'll see that it returns a dictionary of all the collisions. The dictionary will have all of the sprites from group 1 (which is rmg) as the keys, and the value for each key will be a list of every sprite from group 2 (which is rmog) that collided with it. So then to find every sprite that collided from group one, you could do:

```
dict = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(rmg, rmog,True ,True)
for sprite in dict:
    if dict[sprite]:
        print (sprite.x)
```

Also, a couple general tips that are unrelated to your problem,

Don't do this:

```
redmonstre = crmonstre(rmonstre,1)
rmog.add(redmonstre)
redmonstre = crmonstre(rmonstre,1)
rmog.add(redmonstre)
redmonstre = crmonstre(rmonstre,1)
rmog.add(redmonstre)
```

There is no need to have a name for each redmonstre, and it will only make it more confusing to have them all named the same. Instead, just add them directly to the list:

```
rmog.add(crmonstre(rmonstre, 1))
rmog.add(crmonstre(rmonstre, 1))
rmog.add(crmonstre(rmonstre, 1))
```

And don't do this:

```
for redmonstre in rmog:
    fenetre.blit(fond, redmonstre.rect, redmonstre.rect)
    redmonstre.move()
    fenetre.blit(redmonstre.image,redmonstre.rect)
```

Blitting "fond" takes a (relatively) long time. If you blit it for every redmonstre, you will only see the last one. Just blit it once before the loop.

```
fenetre.blit(fond, redmonstre.rect, redmonstre.rect)

for redmonstre in rmog:
    redmonstre.move()
    fenetre.blit(redmonstre.image,redmonstre.rect)
```

Comment: First i want to thanks you for this precise and complete answer, helps me a lot.I quickly tested your second option to get the position it seems to work well. but i still need your help to understand your generals tips I directly added the sprites to the group it worked but before i used redmonstre.rect.x =450 for exemple to set it a new position but now how to do this because my sprite doesnt have a name.

Comment: @luka It depends. Which sprite you want to do it to and why?

Comment: @ DJ McMayhem I always need to control those sprite but i don't know how for exemple if i want to : fenetre.blit(fond, redmonstre.rect, redmonstre.rect) like in your exemple. I can't because redmonstre doesn't exist so how do i call my object to get access to his informations and functions?

Comment: [Here's](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) a list of methods you can call on rmg.